# Protocol Buffers versus JSON or BSON

Tags: c#, json, comparison, protocol-buffers, bson

Does anyone have any information on the performance characteristics of Protocol Buffers versus BSON (binary JSON) or versus JSON in general?

- Wire size
- Serialization speed
- Deserialization speed

These seem like good binary protocols for use over HTTP.  I'm just wondering which would be better in the long run for a C# environment.

Here's some info that I was reading on [BSON](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/12/26/json-net-3-5-release-6-binary-json-bson-support.aspx) and [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html).

Comment: Some argue(I think this includes a former protobuf author) that it's a better idea to use a larger but cheaper to serialize format and then compress the output with a fast standard compressor.

Comment: http://devblog.corditestudios.com/blog/2012/10/29/bson-vs-yaml-vs-protobuf/

Comment: I don't think this should be reopened until a certain comparison method is proposed in the question itself (otherwise this is for rather opinionated discussion/too broad)

Comment: Perhaps more in terms of each format's strengths and weaknesses, and the answer might include a decision tree.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

[Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) is another Protocol Buffers-like alternative as well.

There are good benchmarks from the Java community on serialization/deserialization and wire size of these technologies:  https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki

In general, JSON has slightly larger wire size and slightly worse DeSer, but wins in ubiquity and the ability to interpret it easily without the source IDL.  The last point is something that [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org) is trying to solve, and it beats both in terms of performance.

Microsoft has released a C# NuGet package [Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro/).

Comment: Small message size doesn't automatically translate into fast perforamnce, see this article http://soa.sys-con.com/node/250512

Comment: Good link; the only thing I am not sure about is comment about Avro -- while it could work more efficiently for its core use cases (tons of similar data entries), it does not seem to perform very fast in this benchmark (which tests handling of a single request)

Comment: CoDec, MoDem.... I like "SeDes" better :)

Answer (score 77):

[This post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison.aspx) compares serialization speeds and sizes in .NET, including JSON, BSON and XML.

[image]

[image]

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/01/01/net-serialization-performance-comparison.aspx

Comment: This answer contains NO information about Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 56):

Here are [some recent benchmarks](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/) showing the performance of popular .NET Serializers.

The [Burning Monks benchmarks](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/11/performance-test-json-serializers-part-ii/) show the performance of serializing a simple POCO whilst the comprehensive [Northwind benchmarks](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/NorthwindDatabaseRowsSerialization.100000-times.2010-08-17.html) show the combined results of serializing a row in every table of Microsoft's Northwind dataset.

[image]

Basically protocol buffers ([protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)) is around **7x** quicker than the fastest Base class library Serializer in .NET (XML DataContractSerializer). Its also smaller than the competition as it is also **2.2x** smaller than Microsofts most compact serialization format (JsonDataContractSerializer).

ServiceStack's Text serializers are the closest to matching the performance of the binary protobuf-net where its [Json Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/) is only **2.58x** slower than protobuf-net.

Comment: Great post - but if possible you should always put error bars onto your bar charts when showing averages.

Answer (score 25):

protocol buffers is designed for the wire:

1. very small message size - one aspect is very efficient variable sized integer representation.
2. Very fast decoding - it is a binary protocol.
3. protobuf generates super efficient C++ for encoding and decoding the messages -- hint: if you encode all var-integers or static sized items into it it will encode and decode at deterministic speed.
4. It offers a VERY rich data model -- efficiently encoding very complex data structures.

JSON is just text and it needs to be **parsed**.  hint: encoding a "billion" int into it would take quite a lot of characters: Billion = 12 char's (long scale), in binary it fits in a uint32_t Now what about trying to encode a double ? that would be FAR FAR worse.

Comment: It does, however, have the rather unfortunate downside of not handling inheritance and while composition is a valid alternative, I prefer not to be forced by my data transfer object to use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: I believe Extensions can be used in a way very similar to inheritance... https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#extension

Comment: Yes, extensions is a very good point. I use it in practice at work every day.

Comment: "protocol buffers is designed for the wire"

What is "the wire"?

Comment: @marcospgp `the wire` means just network. Now when we use so many wireless networks it may sound weird.

Comment: @MarcosPereira  think data streamed over a wire (or coax, twisted pair, fiber, whatever).