# What is "expected" or "average" ratio for BSON/JSON file sizes?

Tags: json, bson

Of course the right way would be to save and compare, but I am looking for an average or expected number that I can use for more general project planning. Because I do not have the files yet, and want you to share your experiences with BSON.

Comment: json is a serialization standard. I'm not sure if you'll be able to get an average size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare JSON and BSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601890/compare-json-and-bson)